# Jenkins Deploy Artifacts to Nexus using Deploy to Maven Repository

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus

We have a scenario to deploy the artifact generated from maven build to Nexus. The Jenkins job would run goals `clean package`. The artifact should go to SNAPSHOT repo if the pom.xml has a SNAPSHOT version. If the pom.xml has a release version, the artifact should go to release repo. Any idea how we can achieve this using the Deploy to Maven Repository plugin. As of now I am using the below script in Execute Shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
var2="SNAPSHOT"
if [[ $(echo "$var1"|grep -i "$var2" | wc -l | tr -d ' ') -gt 0 ]]; then
   exit 1
else
   exit 0
fi
```

In Flexible Publish post build action, I am using Execute Shell conditional action. Based on the result of the script, I would execute the Deploy to Maven repository post build action. This can only help to deploy to release repo. Any better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that if you cannot update pom files in repositories, you have two options:

1. There is a [Maven Project plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin), which allows you to add a new post-build action `Deploy artifacts to Maven repository`. It allows you to set repository URL and name, along with few other options. Setting repository with `snapshot` policy as a target one will result in successful upload of snapshot artifacts. Note that

   - the step is available only if build type is `Maven build` (2/3)
   - upload will fail with `Bad request` error if you try to upload release artifact
2. In case adding a plugin is not an option, you can use dirty hack and alter `pom` file on-the-fly as the first build step via something like `sed`. That's risky and should not be used if not absolutely inevitable.

To update all builds at once I'd recommend either use some plugin ([Configuration Slicing plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) as an option) or alter `config.xml` files directly via script from CLI and then use "Reload configuration" in Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this functionality is built into Maven itself; you can specify a different `<repository>` and `<snapshotRepository>` in your `<distrobutionManagement>` block. (See [docs](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repository))

Comment: we have more than 1000 jobs pulling from 1000 git repos. This approach would need all the 1000 projects to update the pom.xml rite?

Comment: Yes, unless they share a common root-pom where you can define common configuration.

Comment: Most of them are legacy apps. Is there any other option?